# Get the value with the right click on cell c# DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working with the next **DataGridView**:

[image]

**I am trying to get the value of the pink cell when I right click on the black cell**, but I don't know how to do it exactly because this gives me the value of the current cell (blue cell) (Code):

```cs
private void abrirIncidencia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

    string nd = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cell seleccionada: " + nd + " current row es: " + currentRowIndex);
    string nOrdFab = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ggConnectionString"].ToString());

    String strSql = "";
    SqlCommand comando;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm, "Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this method is accessed by a **ToolStripMenuItem**:

```
        this.abrirIncidencia.Name = "abrirIncidencia";
        this.abrirIncidencia.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(227, 22);
        this.abrirIncidencia.Text = "Abrir Incidencia";
        this.abrirIncidencia.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.abrirIncidencia_Click);
```

How can I get the value of the pink cell when I right click over the black cell?

**EDIT**:
In this method I am using EventsArgs but if I try to change to **MouseEventArgs** tell me the next error:

> No overhead corresponding to 'openClick_Incidence' matches the
>   'System.EventHandler'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: DataGridView has an event CellClick(). Use it, instead of event Click() that you use now. Then, parameter e has a rowIndex, use it to get your pink cell.

Comment: Don't understant it, using this dataGridView1.CellClick? @VDN

Comment: Post updated with new information.

Comment: You need to be handling the `DataGridView.CellClick` event rather than the `DataGridView.Click` event. The `CellClick` event has has the signature `DataGridViewCellEventHandler(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`. `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` has a property for `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex`. Use `e`'s `RowIndex` property instead of the `CurrentRow` property of the `DataGridView`.

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman thank you for your response. I am new with these structures so have I something to change in the designer or just in the class?

Comment: @LuckWallace In the designer: Remove the handler for the `Click` Event in the `DataGridView`, then double click the empty box for the `CellClick` event to make a new, proper handler for that. Then, from there, copy over your current handling, replacing all references to `DataGridView.CurrentRow` to `DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex)`

Comment: What is the COLUMN NAME of the pink cell ?

Comment: @SQLPolice is 1, I am doing by index, and the Column is in the position 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the DataGridView's CellClick event instead:

```
dataGridView1.CellClick += New DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick)
```

Make a function to handle this, with the correct signature:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    try {
        string nd = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cell seleccionada: " + nd + " current row es: " + e.RowIndex);
        string nOrdFab = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ggConnectionString"].ToString());

        String strSql = "";
        SqlCommand comando;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm, "Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

It would also be beneficial to remove the Try Catch once you have this code fully operational - or at least only catch external errors thrown from the SqlAdapter. Also, if your columns are created in the designer, then your form will have a field for each column - such as `IDDataGridViewTextboxColumn` - which you can access the index of like `IDDataGridViewTextboxColumn.Index` to simplify and clarify which column you are accessing. This would make the declaration of nOrdFab much more clear; for example:

```
string nOrdFab = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[IDDataGridViewTextboxColumn.Index].Value.ToString();
```

**EDIT:** If you're trying to do the work in a `ContextMenuStrip` event handler, then you still need to handle the `CellClick` event to set the current cell's selection to the one that was right clicked, but will need to use the `CurrentCell` property again in the event handler for the `ToolStripMenuItem's` `Click` event.

The CellClick Handler:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.RowIndex >= 0) {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    }
}
```

Then the context menu item handler:

```
private void abrirIncendia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        string nOrdFab = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ggConnectionString"].ToString());

        String strSql = "";
        SqlCommand comando;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Form.ActiveForm, "Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your job Zaelin. I forget to say that this method is called using a ToolStripMenuItem. I've updated the post. Would have a difference now with this?

Comment: @LuckWallace I've edited my answer to fit this scenario.